# ZSH: автокомплит показывает неверные имена файлов через scp

Tags: linux, zsh, scp

В ZSH при вызове завершения файлов у scp через TAB, в списке не появляются каталоги вместо них один пункт `^M`, а у файлов в конце названия добавляется `^M`.

Если выбрать из списка завершения файл то это будет выглядеть так:
`scp work-machine:/etc/fstab\$\'\\r\'`

Пробовал вывести список файл на других машинах, там такой проблемы нет.

**sshd_config**

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 5
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
AllowUsers user
PermitRootLogin no
MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 10
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

**.zshrc**

```
setopt NO_BEEP
setopt AUTO_CD
setopt COMPLETEALIASES
setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
setopt NO_HIST_BEEP
setopt HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS
setopt SHARE_HISTORY

zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i

bindkey -e

autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
bindkey  "^[[1~"   beginning-of-line
bindkey  "^[[H"    beginning-of-line
bindkey  "^[[4~"   end-of-line
bindkey  "^[[F"    end-of-line
bindkey  "^[[3~"  delete-char
```

**Вот как это выглядит:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец-то я нашел причину своей проблемы.

У меня в файле `~/.ssh/config` в настройках хоста для рабочей машины было установлено `RequestTTY force`, после того как поменял на `auto`, `scp` заработал нормально и остальное тоже вроде работает без ошибок.